# Install latest version of libc++

Tags: software-installation, clang

While I know, that I can install the latest clang compiler for xenial from http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ (Doku: https://apt.llvm.org/) I could not determine how to install the latest version of libc++ (llvm's standard library implementation).

Is there a separate repository for that or do I have to manually download and compile the latest version of that library?

Btw.:
I know that clang will use libstdc++ by default and most of the time that is OK for me, but sometimes I like to experiment / test my code with libc++ or use features that are not yet part of libstdc++.

Comment: If it is not in the repos you have to find a ppa, .deb, or compile it yourself. Support for doing so is going to be limited at best.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Do you know a place, where I could find a repository / package containing libc++?

Comment: Only http://releases.llvm.org/download.html

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Thanks, but unfortunately that page only provides the sources for libc++(unless I overlooked something).

Comment: That is the only source I could find period. No ppa or repo available, often the case when you want the latest available - https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: *"often the case when you want the latest available"* I know. However, as there IS a repo for the latest llvm/clang, as well as for libstdc++, the idea, that a repos for libc++ would exist is not that far-fetched.

Comment: *"Funny though, you want the latest greatest c++ but are afraid to compile it, lol."* Who said I was afraid of it? In fact thats what I've done so far, but I was wondering / hoping that there is a better solution.